# Why CHAR column comparing to numeric literal return true?

Tags: mysql

This bug my mind I have this table

```sql
CREATE TABLE `t_slot` (
  `id` int unsigned NOT NULL,
  `uid` int unsigned NOT NULL,
  `code` char(9) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `pType` tinyint unsigned NOT NULL,
  `pos` tinyint unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `pid` int unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `lChild` int unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `rChild` int unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `encodeTime` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `code` (`code`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Then I tried to do query something like this

```sql
SELECT * FROM t_slot WHERE code = 5;
```

And with a big surprise it match 1 row with value of

```sql
mysql> select * from t_slot where code = 5;
+----+-----+-----------+-------+------+------+--------+--------+---------------------+
| id | uid | code      | pType | pos  | pid  | lChild | rChild | encodeTime          |
+----+-----+-----------+-------+------+------+--------+--------+---------------------+
|  2 |   4 | 5FPSLB-BP |    40 |    0 |    1 |      3 |      5 | 2022-03-19 17:39:03 |
+----+-----+-----------+-------+------+------+--------+--------+---------------------+
1 row in set, 50 warnings (0.00 sec)
```

And got this warnings

```sql
mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                       |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'Y8VHM9-BP' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '5FPSLB-BP' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'HBV29S-BP' |
... etc
```

I didn't really expect that 5 will match with `5FPSLB-BP`.

How does 5 is equal to `5FPSLB-BP`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value" -- Show us the command that caused these.  It sounds like `LOAD DATA` without the `OPTIONALLY QUOTED` or something.

`WHERE code = 5` -- When comparing a `CHAR`-type column to a numeric literal (`5`), the string is converted to numeric.  Yeah, that is surprising, but that is what happens in MySQL.

Since `code` is "5FPSLB-BP", you should probably quote the string you are comparing it to:  `WHERE code = "5"`.  In that case the test will correctly fail.